# C++: function inside class for multiple variable values

Tags: c++, function, enums, redefinition

a bit of a noob problem. Inside a class called 'cell', I have an enum 'Example' say

```
  typedef enum Example
  {
      E1=0,
      E2,
      E3,
      E4
  };
  Example inputValueE;
```

Also I have a function inside class as follows

```
  void evolveE(Example type_);
```

Outside the class, I attempt to define the function for several types as follows

```
void cell::evolveE(Example type_ = E1){****some stuff****;};
void cell::evolveE(Example type_ = E2){****some diff stuff****;}; ***etc***
```

I've played around with these a bit but with no luck. The problem is i'm not allowed to redefine the same function. I was going to use the switch-case type command which is always backup although i'm pretty sure there is a more elegant way to do this

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered the query above. I decided to use Polymorphism. In any event all three answers I tried worked equally well, and since each Ei are unique and will contain a lot of diff functions etc on each of them, polymorphism is the way i'm going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When overloading a function (providing more than one function with the same name in a class), you need to provide a different set of argument *types* to each function like this:

```
void cell::evolveE(Example type_){****some stuff****;}
void cell::evolveE(OtherExample size_){****some diff stuff****;}
```

Notice that here, one function takes an argument of type `Example` and the other takes an argument of type `OtherExample`. Although you provide different default values in the function you are trying to overload, both functions take the same argument *type* and so the compiler has no way of telling the difference between them.

You could use a switch although I would prefer an if/else because it is less prone to bugs.

If the `Example` enum is really determining the *type* of your class you could use polymorphism. It is a very elegant feature of OOP. Then you could have something like this:

```
class cell
{
    ...
    virtual void evolveE() = 0;
};

class E1cell : public cell
{
    ...
    void evolveE()
    {
        // some stuff
    }
};

class E2cell : public cell
{
    ...
    void evolveE()
    {
        // some diff stuff
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That syntax sets a default argument.  It does not match the actual parameter passed by the caller.  Use `switch`/`case`.

If you want to be fancy, you could also use an array (or map) of function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

For this statement:

```
void cell::evolveE(Example type_ = E1);
```

Two points:

1. Here you are setting a default value for `evolveE`'s parameter and
   not making it to take a type of `enum`
2. You cannot overload functions based on values of any kind; function
   can be overloaded only with different types and number of parameters

One of the solution:

You can choose to use make every value an independent type:

```
enum E1 {};
enum E2 {};
enum E3 {};
```